# Laravel droplist from the database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am newbie in laravel and I like to have a droplist with the values from the database table. How can I do it, actually I have an error: "Undefined variable: claims" (I think data is not passing) - I think it's because of few reasons: because of View function or different reasons.

If you have a droplist code and you can explain your code with details - please, share it with me!

[Example of a droplist I like to have(taking the values from the db):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld5Wz.png)

Definitions of my values and variables:

```
mainpage - my html page

Drop - my table with the name "claim_type" in the db

$claims - variable with info from the table "claim_type" from the database
```

Yea, I declared my table with function

```
protected $table = 'claim_type';
```

Here is my Controller with the name MainController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Main;
use App\Drop;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $claims = Drop::all();
        return View::make('mainpage')->with('users', $claims);
    }
```

And my html:

```
@extends('layout.mainlayout')

@section('content')
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/') }}/querty">
{{ csrf_field()}}
<div>
         <h2>Force form:</h2>
    <p> You can add you information here, Sir:</p>
    <p> Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    </p>
    <p> Email:
        <input type="text" name="email" />
    </p>
    <div>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/') }}/add">
    @foreach($claims as $claim) 
    <option value="$claim->id">{{$claim->type}}</option> 
    @endforeach
    </form>
    </div>
    <p> Where:
        <input type="text" name="where" />
    </p>
    <p> Description:
        <input type="text" name="description" />
    </p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Explose it!</button>

</div>
</form>
@endsection
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/mainpage', 'MainController@index');
```

Actually, saw a lot of articles, please explain me how it works.

Thank you!

I hope this post will help also for the different coders

Tested methods from different users:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $claims = Drop::all();
        dd($claims);
        return View::make('mainpage')->with(claims);
    }
```

In Views (tested methods):

```
@foreach($claims as $claim)
        <option value="$claim->id">{{$claims->type}}</option>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Please don't include answers in your question. Answers form other users should just stand on their own (and be upvoted/accepted), any solutions of your own should also go into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On index method in controller yo have two errors

$claims = Drop::all()->get();// use this get()

return `View::make('mainpage')->with('users', claims);`// you don`t need $

And where did you get this users

And in view you need foreach

```
 @foreach($claims as $claim)
    <option value="$claim->id">{{$claims->type}}</option>
@endforeach
```

And also i think that your model don`t see your table in db because of naming convention. Model name is plural of your db table name. If you have table claimTypes model is claimType

Comment: Dear Zoran Kabic, your method doesnt work. Yea, laravel sees my db, i declared it like this: protected $table = 'claim_type';

Comment: dump $claims and show  us results and i do have mistake about $. I usually use compact('users', 'claims')

Comment: Sorry, how and where dump $claims?

Comment: dd($claims); in controller after $claims = Drop::all(); if you get data problem is in your view because you di not use foreach loop

Comment: and don`t need ->get(); I was read on phone at first and did not see well

Comment: And also my return usually looks like this return view('mainpage', compact( 'claims' );

Comment: Yes, it's problem with view. Thanks for your help, but your code didn't help me. Actually a problem with view file

Comment: can you send your droplist example? Thanks

Comment: i think yu nedd this  @foreach($claims as $claim)
    <option value="$claim->id">{{$claim->type}}</option>
@endforeach

Comment: bow I have new problem: Undefined variable: claims. It means view doesnt see values. Maybe I have problem with route?

Comment: return view as i do like return view('mainpage', compact( 'claims' ) and also  <option value="$claim->id"> change into  <option value="{{ $claim->id }}">

Comment: I did but it doesnt work.  Probably problem with form in html file or Route::post('/mainpage', 'MainController@index');

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the code is correct. Thanks to the Zoran Kabic's help, I fixed the bug.

**My error was: for each form Route we can call only one controller. For example, we can't add few Controllers.**

Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');

Route::get('/', 'DropController@index');//incorrect, only one controller for each path

My code, it's woking well and tested at 146%:

[The result of my code, values are taking from the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx6zD.jpg)

Routing:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index'); //you need to use get method,
     //and your controller and index (in my case it's MainContoller and @index - index)
```

Model (in my case it's named as Drop.php):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Eloquent;
class Drop extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = 'claim_type'; //table name in your DB

}
```

Controller (in my case MainController.php)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Drop; //using our Model

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

    $claims = Drop::all();//taking the values from db to variable

    return view('mainpage', ['claims'=> $claims]); //value to the view from the value $claims

    }
```

Thanks for all!
Hope my answer will help sb in the future!